# Update multiple rows and columns using respective ids in mssql

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server

I extracted data from database in excel format using sql join query. I modified few columns data in to that exce sheet. I want update modified data into database using respective row ids.
When I iterate stack: `Error: aborted` is thrown.

below is my code

```
sql.connect(db, async (err)=> {
  if (err)
    console.log(err);
  var request = new sql.Request();
var workbook = XLSX.readFile('2021-08-30-202129.xlsx');
var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
var xlData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[1]]);
console.log(xlData);
xlData.forEach(async (item)=>{
  let returnquery = await ` UPDATE [billing] SET notes='${item.notes}' WHERE id='${item.id}'`
    request.query(returnquery, function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
      else{
        console.log('result', result);
      }
      sql.close();
    }); 
  })
  });
```

Comment: No idea what's causing your issue, but you have a major SQL injection problem here, you need to use `request.input` to parameterize

Answer (score 2):

I typically use the workbench app, and open a query window, to ensure I have the correct SQL syntax.  (console.log your sql statement right before you call the DB, then copy it over to the workbench).

I usually have some small typo issue, and this allows me to easily figure that out, then go back to the code and fix the error.

I also think you have issues with having ' by your variables.  those should be removed since you're already in `` style.  SQL will misinterpret those.